# In C# EF, does Where(o=>o.Equals(x)) get treated as a client-side func?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Came across code where `.Where(o => o.x == y)` was changed to `.Where(o => o.x.Equals(y))`. I knew that `==` was parsed out by EF's SQL generator to execute on the server, but wasn't sure about `.Equals()`. Clearly this change was done as a matter of habit, perhaps someone coming out of a C++ background and not thinking about the fact that `==` would have been parsed as an expression, not executed as a function, and would be converted to SQL. This change compiles and runs but I was wondering if it's because EF is treating it as a Func instead of as an expression, and as such perhaps executing a generalized query and moving the filter to client-side, or something similarly ridiculous.

Comment: It is easy to figure out using SQL profiler.

Comment: `.Equals() ` is probably a cleaner solution so that EF will properly handle Object equality at runtime, prior to translating to SQL.

Comment: @JamesC.TaylorIV How can it do that? in OP's case it doesnt know that value `o` has?

Comment: @JamesC.TaylorIV that sentence is complete nonsense from start to end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq-To-Entities, as of version 6 of EF, doesn't perform any kind of filtering in the client. If you try to execute any kind of not supported function (meaning it can't be translated to the DB provider) on an EF's `IQueryable`, it'll throw an exception.

So the answer is: no, it's not executing it locally.

*PS:* I've read somewhere that this feature is a planned addition to EF7, but this is unconfirmed and just speculation

**Update**: link to source here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/27/ef7-v1-or-v7.aspx

Quoting the relevant part in case the link goes dead:

> An example of this is how queries are processed. In EF6.x the entire LINQ query was translated into a single SQL query that was executed in the database. This meant your query could only contain things that EF knew how to translate to SQL and you would often get complex SQL that did not perform well.
>
> In EF7 we are adopting a model where the provider gets to select which bits of the query to execute in the database, and how they are executed. This means that query now supports evaluating parts of the query on the client rather than database. It also means the providers can make use of queries with multiple results sets etc., rather than creating one single SELECT with everything in it.

Comment: Agree - it ends up generating the exact same SQL

Answer (score 0):

I ran SQL Profiler. It generated "[table].[x] = 'y'" as was originally intended with '=='.

Comment: Note that `as hoped` could be misleading if your object has overriden `Equals()` since you'd be using the SQL equality comparer, and not your own. It's the ***expected*** conversion to SQL, but if I was to ***hope***, I'd "hope" it'd honor the equality comparison defined in the object (which is just not possible) :-)

Comment: It might be interesting to see what the behavior would be if it is indeed overridden. Perhaps an exception will be thrown, detecting that it is not System.Object.Equals() but another implementation that was expressed. (Unfortunately, not quite interesting enough for my part to actually do another test, since I've moved on. Hehe..)

Comment: It will not take into account the custom `Equals()` and will use the default implementation. This is documented here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Support%20of%20POCO%20entities%20with%20custom%20Equals%20and%20GetHashCode%20implementations . On the first line: "EF6 will support POCO entities that have custom Equals or GetHashCode implementations. **EF will instead use the default implementations**."

Comment: (Note that this is valid only for the "SQL conversion part", it'll still use your equality and hashcode checks on the returned `HashSet` unless it's proxied, but this is on the realm of Linq-To-Objects really)